# How to get sprite following mouse position when camera is rotated 30 degree on X axys on UNITY3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a sprite following my mouse position with my camera rotated at 30 on x axys, this works fine if camera have a rotation of 0,0,0 but not on 30,0,0, how I have to calculate this? I have tryed substracting to x position with no success, here is my code:

this is attached on the object I want to follow the mouse

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 pos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

EDIT: also my camera is ortographic not perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScreenToWorldPoint` isn't really appropriate here because you don't already know the proper distance to put the sprite away from the camera. Instead, consider using a raycast (algebraically, using `Plane`) to figure where to put the sprite.

Create an XY plane at the sprite's position:

```
Plane spritePlane = new Plane(Vector3.forward, transform.position);
```

Create a ray from the cursor's position using [`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html):

```
Ray cursorRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

Find where that ray intersects the plane and put the sprite there:

```
float rayDist;
spritePlane.Raycast(cursorRay, out rayDist);
transform.position = cursorRay.GetPoint(rayDist);
```

Altogether:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Plane spritePlane = new Plane(Vector3.forward, transform.position);
    Ray cursorRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    float rayDist;
    spritePlane.Raycast(cursorRay, out rayDist);

    transform.position = cursorRay.GetPoint(rayDist);
}
```

Comment: You should then consider to not put it in `FixedUpdate` but either `Update` or `LateUpdate` (if e.g. the camera can move)

Comment: But if my camera is ortographic I still have to use raycast? couldn't I calculate the distance of the sprite somehow since my camera is locket on Z but not on X, Y

Comment: @Sociopath If you're trying to ask "is using `Raycast` inefficient?", the answer is no, because `Plane.Raycast` [only does a line or two of vector math](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld017.htm). You could implement it yourself, but that's not really necessary when `Plane.Raycast` already exists.

Comment: Thanks I learned a lot, and also your code works like a charm, btw on ScreenPointToRay its cam.ScreenPointToRay (the main camera)